# send multiple mails using php

Tags: php, html, html-email

I wrote a script in order to send emails using `PHP` to multiple users using Bcc tag but it doesn't work. The result is that only one mail is sent (to `$to`) and more over in email there is not my newsletter but there is my `HTML` and `PHP`code. here there is the first part of my code

### PHP

```
$to = "b********@gmail.com";
$emailList="b***********@gmail.com,f************i@gmail.com,b************@gmail.com";

$subject = 'Newsletter ';

$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));

$headers = "From: My site<info@*****t.it>\r\nReply-To: info@****.it";

$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
$headers .= "Bcc: $emailList\r\n";
```

If I delete the second(`$emailList="b***********@gmail.com,f************i@gmail.com,b************@gmail.com";`) row and last row(`$headers .= "Bcc: $emailList\r\n";`) it works perfectly

Comment: Try like this `$headers .= "Bcc:".$emailList."\r\n";`

Comment: @arunrc It's the same.

Comment: Try "Bcc: {$emailList}\r\n"